# UML use case diagram - Framework as an actor?

Tags: uml, use-case

I am working on a project where I'll first create a framework for the iOS platform(pod) and after that I will implement this framework in an actual iOS application to show the use of it. The framework is supposed to gather data about the user's face from the camera and the heart rate from an Apple watch.

Now when it comes to modeling this in a use case diagram I am unsure. Should I show both the user and  the framework as actors in one use case diagram? And then show that the use case that provides the data about the user is the framework's job?

Comment: https://www.uml-diagrams.org/use-case-diagrams.html The boundary is your "framework", I'd guess. Actually, I don't understand your vocabulary when talking of a framework as actor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the User is an Actor and the framework is an implementation detail that you could model in several ways depending on what you want to show. For example, it could be represented in terms of the module structures (libraries), class structures within these, component models and/or deployment models, state charts, sequence charts and so on. Who is your audience and what do you want to covey? Are you using UML to help you through the design process, i.e. using formal languages to get you to think about the right things and answer the right questions? Answering these will help direct you to an approach.

Answer (score -1):

UML use case diagrams are made according to the activities of active assets.